# Solving a differential equation with constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Gilbert Strang's Differential Equations and Linear algebra notebook, he mentions that, $$y(t) = e^{at}y(0) + q/a(e^{at}-1)$$ can be used to solve $$y'- ay = q(t)$$ if q(t) is constant.
Well I am doing a practice problem *(not from Gilbert's book)* and my answer doesn't match the correct answer. I am required to solve $$x'=Ix-q$$ where I is a constant interest rate per year and q is constant rate of withdrawing money from the bank. And x is the amount of money in the bank.
Now using the formula from Gilbert's book I came up with $$x=Ce^{It}-q/I(e^{It})+q/I$$ but but the right solution is apparently $$Ce^{It}+q/I$$ My solution has that extra middle term, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For the problem, what is your initial condition?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan, I think it would be x(0)= 0, because at time zero, no interest or withdrawn is in effect. The question doesn't give initial condition. Here is the question: Scrooge McDuck wants to set up a trust fund for his nephew Don. He has fool-proof investments which make a constant interest rate of I, measured in units of (years)−1 (so I = 0.05 means 5% per year), and he proposes to dole out the money to his profligate nephew at a constant rate q dollars per year.

Comment: Check answer below, it's a rather simple difference :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $q$ is a constant, couldn't you just use

$$\int\frac{dx}{Ix-q} = \int dt$$

$$\implies \frac{\ln(Ix-q)}{I} = t+A$$

$$\implies Ix-q = Ce^{It}$$

$$\implies x = C'e^{It} + q/I$$

Now if you apply the formula, what you get is

$$x = (C-q/I)e^{It} + q/I$$

What the book has done is called the constant $(C-q/I)$ as another constant $C$, if you get what I mean

Comment: Oh wow lol, that wasn't too complicated. Thanks